# Gap on the left side of the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
.navbar a {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
  }
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
    }
  }
body {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    font-family: 'Cabin Condensed';
    font-size: 18pt;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: #08bdbd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 0 18px 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
h1 span {
    border: 4px dashed #08bdbd;
    padding: 10px;
}
p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.img-circle {
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.section {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.form {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#header {
    background-image: url("banner.png");
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.social {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#contacts img:hover {
    opacity: 0.8
}
.quote {
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
ul {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
textarea {
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 40px;
    min-width: 70%;
    max-width: 70%;
}
input, textarea {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    background-color: #efefef;
    color: #787575;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 70%;
    outline: none;
}
.submit:hover {
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

.copyright {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
 <a class="active" href="#about">About Me</a>
 <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
 <a href="#schedule">Schedule</a>
 <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any default padding on the `<body>` tag?

Comment: HTML has no default padding nor margin. Please do not listen to Md Junaid Alam's answer. Just remove the default margin of 8px from your body tags or do what Marshmallow told you.

Comment: @Stacks, I agree to you, that there is no default padding to body.  In this case padding:10px in  style for body {...} is causing the extra space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods to fix this.

### Method 1:

Try adding `left: 0px;` to the `.navbar` selector.
Here is your code:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
   <a class="active" href="#about">About Me</a>
   <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
   <a href="#schedule">Schedule</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Here is a living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/gOarVVo

### Method 2:

Add `margin: 0;` to the `body` selector.
Here is your code:

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
    
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#about">About Me</a>
  <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
  <a href="#schedule">Schedule</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Here is a living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/KKdMPKJ

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
After you updated css code. padding in the `body` is causing extra space.

```
body {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    font-family: 'Cabin Condensed';
    font-size: 18pt;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px; /*Set it to 0*/
    margin: 0;
}
```

`body` tag have default margins. Reset it to 0;

```css
body {
margin:0;
}
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
.navbar a {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
  }
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
 <a class="active" href="#about">About Me</a>
 <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
 <a href="#schedule">Schedule</a>
 <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `HTML` tags do not have any default `margin` neither `padding`. Also, body tags have no default `padding`. They have a default `margin` of `8px`.

Comment: I added the full css code because that didn't fix it. Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: @Ian Yes, add `left:0` to your `.navbar` I just tried it on my computer.

Comment: @Ian in you css for body {padding: 10px;} Remove this padding. It is causing the space.